# Using Cloudkit Assets as a UIimage

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckquery, ckasset

I have images saved in CloudKit as an asset. There are other attributes for each record as well. I can gather the record and use the other attributes, but I'm unable to use the asset in my ImageView. I'm new to Swift programming, therefore the error I receive does not make any sense.

```
let container = CKContainer.default()
let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase    

let query1 = CKQuery(recordType: "movieArray", predicate: predicate2)
    publicDB.perform(query1, inZoneWith: nil) {(results:[CKRecord]?, error:Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Cloud Query Error - Fetch Establishments: \(String(describing: error))")
            }
            return
        }
        for record in results! {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let asset = record["myImageKey"] as? CKAsset
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: (asset?.fileURL)!)
                let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                print("Test")
                self.detailImage.image = image
            }
            self.movieCast.text = record.object(forKey: "Actors") as? String
            self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = record.object(forKey: "Description") as? String
            let youLink = record.object(forKey: "youtubeTag") as! String
            self.loadYoutube(videoID: youLink)
        }
    }
```

The error I get is on this line:

```
let data = NSData(contentsOf: (asset?.fileURL)!)
```

it says:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1020527c4
```

I attempted to remove it from the main thread, but I receive the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that the `CKAsset` record is nil, but you are *forcing* to have a `fileURL` value.

Try to obtain CloudKit image with this snippet

```
if let asset = record["myImageKey"] as? CKAsset,
   let data = try? Data(contentsOf: (asset.fileURL)),
   let image = UIImage(data: data)
{
    self.detailImage.image = image
}
```

Comment: You were absolutely right. I had an error in my Cloudkit data and it was loading a nil value. Thanks!